# How do I get the referenced element in nested Element.prototype function in JS?

Tags: javascript

Imagine defining a custom nested function to use directly on any DOM element as follows

```
Element.prototype.idx={};

Object.defineProperty(Element.prototype.idx, 'createIdx', {
    value: function(){
        console.log(this);
        this.id='x';
    }
});
```

Then using the nested function to create an id on the element like such

```
const a=document.activeElement; //<body></body>
a.idx.createIdx();
```

The reason for using a nested function is that there are other functions that will be added later such as `removeIdx` to remove the Id on viewport change and the like.

How would one get `this` to return the *element* referenced (the `<body>` element) instead of the `window` object as is currently the case?

Comment: Do not put nested objects on the prototype.

Comment: @Bergi It would be important to know why.

Comment: See the duplicates, and your problem with the `this` binding of methods. Methods of an object should live on the object itself, not elsewhere.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it, but it's slightly complicated. Separately, extending built-in prototypes is error-prone. (Doing so can interact with other code in non-obvious, sometimes difficult-to-debug ways. If you do it, though, make sure your new properties are non-enumerable at least.) Given both of those things, you're likely better off creating a function you pass the element to instead.

But again, you *can* do it, by:

1. Making `idx` an accessor property with a getter function.
2. Having the getter function create different objects on demand that bind `this` to their methods (probably by using arrow functions), storing those objects in a [`WeakMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WeakMap) keyed by the element instance.

Along the way, use `Object.defineProperty` to ensure that the `idx` property is non-enumerable.

Like this:

```js
const idxValues = new WeakMap();
Object.defineProperty(Element.prototype, "idx", {
    get() {
        let values = idxValues.get(this);
        if (!values) {
            values = {
                createIdx: () => {
                    console.log(this);
                    this.id = "x";
                },
            };
            idxValues.set(this, values);
        }
        return values;
    },
});

const a = document.activeElement; //<body></body>
a.idx.createIdx();
console.log(a.id); // "x"
```

The `WeakMap` will keep the `values` object for a given element until/unless that element doesn't exist anymore, at which point (or sometime afterward) the entry in the `WeakMap` will be removed (which lets the memory for the object and function be reclaimed) since it's no longer accessible by anything. (By design, `WeakMap` contents are not enumerable; if you don't have the key, you can't get the value, so the value can be removed when the key object no longer exists.)

Comment: Dear, Sweet Lord! Crowder did it. Thank you sir and have yourself a merry Christmas.

Comment: @JohnMiller - LOL, you too, and a safe and happy new year!